# Inconsistent performance applying ForegroundActions in a JEditorPane when reading HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I'm building an HTML editor using [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), but I'm getting some inconsistent performance issues with Foreground Actions. I have a simplified version of my editor below that has three actions: change the font color to red or blue, or change the font-size. Now using the following testFile.html file:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Title</title></head>
  <body link="#0000FF" bgcolor="white">
    <font size="4" face="arial" color="black">Some test text</font>
    <font size="3" face="arial" color="black">Some new test text </font>
  </body>
</html>
```

sometimes I can highlight some text in the editor, and press the red or blue color buttons, and it works fine i.e. it changes color. On other occasions (i.e. if I close my JVM and start it up again) the color will not change UNTIL I apply a `StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction` on the same text.

Is there something missing in how I'm applying the `ForegroundActions`? Or might this be some Java bug?

Code below:

```
public class EditorTest extends JFrame{

private JEditorPane editorPane;
    public EditorTest() 
    {
    editorPane = new JEditorPane();     
    editorPane.setContentType("text/HTML");        
    getContentPane().add(editorPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    editorPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());


    Action a = new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("RedColor", Color.RED);        
    editorPane.getActionMap().put("RedColor", a);

    JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();

    JButton button = new JButton("blue");
    button.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction (
                        "set-foreground-red", Color.blue));


    bar.add(editorPane.getActionMap().get("font-size-12")).setText("12");
    bar.add(button);
    bar.add(editorPane.getActionMap().get("RedColor")).setText("Red");

    getContentPane().add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setSize(650,600);
    setVisible(true);

    File file = new File("testFile.html");
    FileReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new FileReader(file);
        editorPane.read(reader, null);
    }
    catch (IOException ex){}      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below, I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe. Such anomalies may arise if Swing GUI objects are not constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). The example uses `EventQueue.invokeLater()` accordingly.

[image: StyledEditorTest]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

/** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523445 */
public class StyledEditorTest extends JFrame {

    public StyledEditorTest() {
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setContentType("text/HTML");
        editorPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        editorPane.setText("<hr>Welcome to <b>StackOverFlow!</b><hr>");
        JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
        bar.add(new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("Red", Color.red));
        bar.add(new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("Blue", Color.blue));
        bar.add(new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("12", 12));
        bar.add(new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("14", 14));
        bar.add(new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("16", 16));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(editorPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new StyledEditorTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this. The anomaly happens when there are font tags. If you change the setText line to:

editorPane.setText("<hr>Welcome to <b>StackOverFlow!</b><hr><font size=4 face=arial color=black>Some test text</font>");

then I can reproduce the problem using your code as well (with no other changes). But as I said before, unfortunately it is very unpredictable when it does and does not occur.

Comment: I should clarify that the header line will behave fine, only the text within the font tags behaves mischievously.

Comment: OK, I see it, too. It seems to work correctly with font family names, e.g. face=SansSerif, as specified by [`StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction.html).