# Java coloring characters GUI

Tags: java, swing, text, dictionary, colors

I am making a GUI dictionary program and have an input of letters that need to be highlighted in each words that is display. I was wondering how to do this, it doesn't seem very hard to  color my entire JTextArea, but coloring only certain characters seems to be a little more difficult. I have read about JTextPane where I can use styled fonts, but even that doesn't seem straightforward. I need to parse every dictionary word's character and then change that characters color.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'd want to use `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` to do this sort of thing. You can either use styles, as you've seen, or you could create the contents as HTML and display that, which would be a lot simpler, if less flexible.

The relevant section of the Java Tutorial starts [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own Highlights. See DefaultHighlighter and HighlightPainter.

See the http://java-sl.com/tip_vertical_selection.html example of custom highlights using. You can define any desired colors.