# How to set the model for a Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to set a class as the model for a Jpanel, I have done this for an intro programming class at Uni but it was a very inelegant implementation.  I'm sure there is a good method for setting this but I don't know it/forgot it.

The method I used before was I would pass the model class as a parameter to the view class and then use the model to determine what type of instance it was and then load a specific icon based on this data to the gui.  It is very inefficient in that it always had to check what objects were at a certain location and reload everything.

I feel like this should be fairly straight forward but haven't found the correct answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `JPanel` doesn't have it's own modal, but from the sounds of things, you want to define your own view and model.  This is part of design and programming

Answer (score 2):

> I want to set a class as the model for a JPanel.

Fantastic.  That's exactly what every GUI programmer should do.

> The method I used before was I would pass the model class as a parameter to the view class and then use the model to determine what type of instance it was and then load a specific icon based on this data to the GUI.

You have the right idea.  The model instance needs to be passed to the GUI components so that they can access their part of the model.

In your particular case here, the model should contain methods to get each of the icons, and the GUI components would call the get icon model method(s) appropriate for that component.

In general, if your JPanel has text and button components, your model should contain the contents of those text and button components.  If your JPanel has a component with its own data model, like a JTree, then you can keep the DefaultTreeModel in your model class.

If you want, you can have a model class for every JPanel in your GUI.  Generally, you construct your GUI model so it's logical.

Here's a real example from one of my other answers: [Spirograph GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451793/300257)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `JPanel` used as 'container' for most cases and it haven't own `Model` interface as for instance `JTable` or `JList`

Answer (score 0):

Like they said, JPanel has no model.

But, here is some seed code you can use to try and fake it.

```
public abstract class GPanelModel {
    abstract public void setWhatEver();
    abstract public void getWhatEver();
    abstract public void doWhatEver();
}

public class GPanel<T extends GPanelModel> extends JPanel {
    final T t;
    public GPanel(final T model) {
        t = model;
    }
    public T getModel() {
        return t;
    }
}
```