# Java Library to load a document and tag parts of text

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, styleddocument

I am new to Swing development and I am creating a Java application where a user can load text documents and tag parts of text.

The tagged parts of text would then be highlighted and the user can click on the tagged text to edit/remove the tag. Is there any library/class that I can use to achieve this.

I have already looked at `JTextArea`. But to best of my knowledge it can only display plain text (*correct me if I am wrong*)

To be more clear of what I am looking for:

When you tag a question on Stack Overflow (SO), the tags are highlighted with a little box and highlighting around the tag. I am looking something similar in Java.

So, if the component that I add is say X, then X should be able to hold plain text as well as tagged text. The tagged text should look like the SO tags.

**Edit**

An example for clarification.

*Original Text:*

> This is some sample text.

After tagging, say sample, this is what it should look like:

*With Tagged Text*

[image]

That x is basically a button to remove all tags associated with **sample**.

Answer (score 3):

this can help you [jeditorpane and jtextpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) that sets color using `StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction`. It also illustrates related classes in [`StyledEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My idea is, take a textfield,when we double clik on it set to editable then write tag and hit enter.. then update the tag, for highlighting use setBackground,setForeground with textfield

```
JTextField jt=new JTextField("tag");
```

set it as

```
jt.setEditabe(false);
```

add MouseListener to jt see this LINK [**mouse listener**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

```
jt.addMouseListener(this);
```

write the code in mouseClicked event,if we double click it will set as editable state

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int count=0;
    count=e.getClickCount();
    if(count==2)
    {
        jt.setEditable(true);
        count=0;

    }

}
```

then edit the tag...do rest of the code,i.e update TAG by hitting enter using [**key binding**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) see this LINK

Comment: Thanks but I am not concerned about the event handlers. I need some component that I can use for a complete document, for which `JTextField` is not a good option and also I do not need to tag the whole field/document, just parts of it (like the way you highlight in **Word** or **Acrobat Reader**