# Java SE MVC implementation with Swing

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I've implemented MVC pattern for Java SE with Swing using `PropertyChageSupport` and `PropertyChageListener`. The diagram for implemented MVC is as follows.

[image: Modified MVC Pattern]

In the implementation of `View`, I do property change in `Model` with the help of `Controller`.

`View` contains code like following for Ok button.

```
btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        modelController.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(numberField
            .getText()));
        modelController.setName(nameField.getText());
    }
});
```

Complete code can be found in [SwingMVC](https://github.com/TheKojuEffect/SwingMVC).

Now, My question is, **Do I write above code for `btnOk` in `View` or Should I write it in a method in `Controller`** so that in `View`, I'll be doing

```
btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        modelController.btnOkActionPerformed();
    }
});
```

**Of above two implementations, Which is the preferred way to implement MVC?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a caveat: I'm not a professional or student but a hobbiest, but having said that, my own preference is with your second example,

```
btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        modelController.btnOkActionPerformed();
    }
});
```

The control would have to call methods on the view to extract information, and any methods it would call would be part of an interface that the view implements.  My goal in this is to keep the view as dumb as possible and do almost anything to loosen coupling as much as possible.

Comment: Personally, I would define the interactions between the view/controller/model via a series of interfaces, but, for me, the concept is the same +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yep, it's interfaces all the way down!

Comment: +1 agree; IIUC, `Action`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181906/230513), is one such interface.

Answer (score 4):

Your diagram suggests a [*model–view–presenter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) (MVP) pattern, which is compatible with [Swing application design](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html). In this context, [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is a convenient way to encapsulate application functionality for export from you model. As concrete examples:

- `DefaultEditorKit` and `StyledEditorKit` export useful `Action` types that operate on the `Document` model common to text components. As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513), such actions update the `Document`, which indirectly updates the corresponding view component.
- The `ControlPanel` in the example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) exposes a number of `Action` instances that operate directly on an implicit model of `List<Node>` and `List<Edge>`.

Comment: See also [*Java SE Application Design With MVC, with images*](http://browse.feedreader.com/c/The_skiing_cube/251397735).

Comment: According to [Java SE Application Design With MVC from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html), They're calling this pattern modified MVC, What's difference with MVC and MVP.

Comment: [`Mediator/Controller`](http://lkubaski.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/mvc4.gif?w=600) corresponds roughly to `Presenter`; see also [*MVP: Implementation in Java*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–presenter#Implementation_in_Java).

Comment: @trashgod: I would have linked to [this publication](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf) instead. The wiki page is way too short and misrepresents the actual complexity of the design pattern.

Comment: @tereško: Thanks! Happily, the Potel article is cited among the [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–presenter#References).