# How to change the color for later text in Java?

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt

Sorry if I'm not wording this correctly, but how can I change the text color of future texts in a JTextPane? For example, if the current text is "Hi I'm" and I update the text color, then only the text following after "Hi I'm" will change its color.

Right now I am able to change the all the of the current text color using `setForeground(color)`. So if I type anything after "Hi I'm", then both the current and future text color will change, which is not what I want to happen.

Also, when I try changing the text color of a highlighted text, using `setSelectedTextColor(color`) it does not change it permanently. If the text is highlighted, and I try to change the color, the color will change, but as soon as I unhighlight it, the text color goes back to the default black.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea/9652143#9652143

Comment: Thanks mate, that was very helpful! :D

Comment: Also consider actions defined in the `StyledEditorKit`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19103149/230513).