# Use two different .tff font files in same JComponent

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way I can use two completley different fonts in the same swing component?

I mean like two separate .tff files (processed in any way). Only requirement is that text is editable.

I'm open for external libraries too. That would also work. I'd look for them myself, but this is a minor feature and I'd have to go trought API of every single one of them to see if it's there...

External libaraies that do super AND subscripting are also welcome, as long as I can control the size and height of the script.

Comment: you mean you will add a text with a font and then another text with another font? There is always a way

Comment: Well I've been searching for a way quite a while now, if you know how to do it, help would always be appreciated...

Comment: you said your component should have the power with text editing. What is wrong with JTextPane ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, please write the procedure in an answer. I beg you.

Comment: I will, i just want to make sure that i understand your requirement fully. Don't lose your temper :)

Comment: I wont, don't worry. Just don't ask for a SSCCE for this. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is: `JTextPanet`: has a Document to manage data and *Editor kit* to read and write text with editing capability even with styling( e.g, with font type and color foreground). You can also implement undo-redo options too.

However to satisfy your question i am writing a small snippets with **`StyleDocument`** to show how it works.

[image]

```
  StyledDocument styleDocument =  jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
  Style primaryStyle = styleDocument.addStyle("Primary", null);
  Style secondaryStyle = styleDocument.addStyle("Secondary", primaryStyle);


  StyleConstants.setFontFamily(primaryStyle, "American Captain");
                        // use font-family from your platform
  StyleConstants.setFontSize(primaryStyle, 24);

  StyleConstants.setFontFamily(secondaryStyle, "Bira PERSONAL USE ONLY");
                       // use font-family from your platform
  StyleConstants.setFontSize(secondaryStyle, 20);
  StyleConstants.setForeground(primaryStyle, new Color(0x552AFF));
  StyleConstants.setForeground(secondaryStyle, Color.black);

  try {
      styleDocument.insertString(0, "Title with American Captain font\n\n", primaryStyle);
      styleDocument.insertString(styleDocument.getLength(), "Font demonstration with JTextPane. "
              + "Seriously, it is powerful and has the power to do all kind of styling with text. "
              + "check it out, check its mighty power and be embrassed\n", secondaryStyle);
   } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JTextPaneTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

Every Swing Text component is associated with a model known as Document to manage data. What we have done in this code is that, we set different style instances to the [`StyleDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) associating with the `JTextPane` component. I have assumed that you know how to add the `JTextPane` to the `JFrame` and show it. The two different style `primary` and `secondary` has different foreground and font family: `"American Captain"` and `"Bira PERSONAL USE ONLY"`. You can replace them with font-family available in your platform including `serif` and `sans-serif`. Remember that these style created by `StyleDocument.addStyle()` has parent-child hierarchy relation. The child's style attributes(Foreground, background, font size, font style) will override the parent's attributes.

**However Please go through these tutorial article:**

1. [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) And
2. [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: I did say custom *.ttf files, didn't I? :)

Comment: +1 You can use custom fonts; but, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513), the `StyledEditorKit`'s `Action`s work better with the platform's font families, which typically have convenient unicode glyphs.

Comment: @Karlovsky120, as `trashgod` said, you can use any font you want. Just pass the font name in place of `serif` and(or) `sans-serif`, that's all.

Comment: Let's do it this way. I have `font.ttf` file in src folder of the project. And I have Font object `customFont` in my program. Show me how to get either of these two things to work with what you+ve show above, and I'll give 50 points to whoever does.

Comment: @Karlovsky120, what have you tried? What happens when you create your custom Font? Does the Font automatically get registered with the System? That is can you use the getFontName() method of the Font so that you can use the name with StyledConstants?

Comment: And that was the little detail I was looking for. I think. Let me check.

Comment: @camickr, thanks, i was just about to write these in the answer. Anyway thanks for the response

Comment: @Karlovsky120, look into these [`registerFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#registerFont%28java.awt.Font%29) function of `GraphicsEnvironment`

Comment: It works, I love you all. I'll give 50 points to @Sage , since he was here longer, and he has way less points than you camickr . Thank you again.