# Java Swing JEditorPane insert bold tags around selection

Tags: java, swing

I'm using Java Swing and I have a JEditorPane with content type "text/html"

Currently the only content I have in the editor pane is:

```
<html><p>This is a short sentence</p></html>
```

What I want is the user to be able to select any part of that sentence with their mouse. When they hit a button (boldButton_), it needs to bold the text inside their selection.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. This is the code I have so far, which is the event handler on the bold button. The best I can do is insert some text wrapped in bold at the start of the paragraph that has selected text, but what i want is to insert bold tags around the selected text only, so the effect is to bold the selection like you would in any word processor.

Thanks in advance.

```
JEditorPane editArea_;


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // bold button
    if (e.getSource() == boldButton_) {
        
        
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) editArea_.getDocument();
        HTMLEditorKit ekit = (HTMLEditorKit) editArea_.getEditorKit();
        
        int selectStart = editArea_.getSelectionStart();
        int selectEnd = editArea_.getSelectionEnd();
        Element startElem = doc.getParagraphElement(selectStart);
        Element endElem = doc.getParagraphElement(selectEnd);
                        
        // for now only bold if some text has been selected with the mouse
        if (selectStart != selectEnd) {
            
            // 1. text is selected
            // toggle bold tags around the text
            try {
                doc.insertAfterStart(startElem, "<b>WTF</b>");
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                
            
        } 
        editArea_.requestFocusInWindow();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [StyledEditorKit.BoldAction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.BoldAction.html)?

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) illustrates using `StyledEditorKit.BoldAction`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i'm not sure, but you can try this code.

```
 // toggle bold tags around the text
 String txt = doc.getSelectedText();
 if (selectStart != selectEnd) {
    try {
        // doc.insertAfterStart(startElem, "<b>WTF</b>");
        doc.remove(selectStart, selectEnd-selectStart);
        ekit.insertHTML((HTMLDocument) doc.getDocument(), selectStart, "<b>"+txt+"</b>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.B);
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ah ok that is a step in the right direction. It does bold the selection. Follow up question for you though. If the selection spans multiple paragraphs, how would I bold the selection in that case without deleting the paragraphs? If I call doc.remove on a selection spanning multiple paragraphs, it deletes the paragraphs and joins the selection into a single paragraph. Is there a way to maybe iterate through each paragraph that is a part of the selection?

Comment: I've never tried it. but as a note for the bold button, Don't create your own Action. Use the Actions provided by the editor kit. For example: `JButton bold = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );` because when you try to make bold text also underlining, the parameters can be a problem in some circumstances.